# Set default value in Spring Data Cassandra

Tags: java, spring, spring-data, spring-data-cassandra

Basically I want to know, how I can set the default values to Pojo variables , if got null values?

I use Spring-data-Cassandra within my project. Some of entries in Boolean columns has **null**, and when I fetch records from database it throws error as:

> boolean values can't be null

Even I have face same issue with `int` / `long` / `double` ... columns.

So I want to give these field a default value when the column of the database is null.

This is the final example I hope:

```
@Column(default = "UNKNOWN")
private String name;

@Column(default = -1)
private int age;

// or

private String name = "UNKNOWN";
private int age = -1;
```

I have learned about `Converter` / `Mapping` / `TypeDecode` ... but I have nothing.

Please help me.

Comment: You can set default at the entity class levels like `private String name = "DEFAULT"`.

Answer (score 1):

I think you have some mistake in architecture. If you can't accept null in POJO how did null values get to DB? May be you have to accept nulls from DB?

Anyway you can create setters and make null checker with setting default value in these methods.

Comment: Cassandra don't allow to assign default value,we have added column to existing table and in that column Cassandra assign null values.

Comment: But I'm talking about POJO classes. Why can't you to create setters in them and set default value there?

Comment: i want know how i can set default value in POJO classes as i don't know how to do that,if you can help with small POJO exmaple, it will be great.

Comment: null value records not has been written via POJO,that has been added while adding column in Cassandra table.

Comment: something like this:
public void setSomeBoolean(Boolean b){
  if(b == null){
    this.someBoolean = false;
  } else {
    this.someBoolean = b;
  }
}

Answer (score 0):

Use the [`@AccessType` annotation](https://docs.spring.io/spring-data/commons/docs/current/api/org/springframework/data/annotation/AccessType.html) to make sure Spring Data accesses properties through the setters and getters. Then you can put your conversion from `null` values to default values in the setters. Of course, the setters need to accept the boxed types. Not sure, if this means the fields have to be boxed types as well.